# Using Servlet 3.0 with Weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish-3, weblogic-10.x

I am working on a form-based authentication and using following statements. I have realized on the way of implementation that HttpServletRequest->login method comes with servlet 3.0.(with help of stackoverflow users)

```
HttpServletRequest request = getHttpServletRequest();
request.login()
```

So I am using weblogic as an AppServer, I have prepared a war file without any compilation error and it works at glassfish 3.1 appserver. But since weblogic 10.3 has implicit support 2.5 it overwrites Servlet 3.0.1.jar so having following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.login(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

How I can run my war file with servlet 3.0 api on weblogic 10.3 , in other words how I can stop weblogic overwriting servlet 3.0 api?

Comment: Simple answer - you cannot. The servlet API is just the API, not an implementation. You must migrate to a newer WebLogic version... it might be possible to integrate another container, but I'd rather not try that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Weblogic 10.3.x** is a **Servlet 2.5** container.You have to use [**Weblogic 12c**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html) and above . It provides [support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm#BGGBIJBI) for **Servlet 3.0** .

Comment: Thanks. I do not want to migrate weblogic 10.3 to new version at least in a short term. Therefore I have to find ou how to perform form-based authentication via Servlet 2.5

Comment: @AhmetKarakaya did you find any solution for your problem?

Comment: yes I did, I have left weblogic alone forever and moved Springboot :)