# Relationship among Application Server, Container, and Java EE new releases

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, weblogic, glassfish-3

I came accross two cases before;

**at first case,** I realized that I could not use Servlet 3.0 in Weblogic 10.3.x since Weblogic 10.3.x is Servlet 2.5 container
[Using Servlet 3.0 with Weblogic 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230082/using-servlet-3-0-with-weblogic-10-3)

**at second case,** Glassfish can be configured for new jSF release by replacing jar files under modules with new ones.
[How do I upgrade the JSF API in GlassFish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792222/how-do-i-upgrade-glassfish-jsf-api)

The point is that what is the relationship among Application server, Container and Java EE new release?
I mean when container JSF releases new version does Application server need to upgrade itself?
Same concern for Java EE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java EE is a collection of services. A particular version of Java EE specifies the version of each service container (e.g. Servlet).

An application server hosts containers for different services (e.g. Servlet). A particular version of an app server typically comes bundled with certain versions of containers for different services, which typically match a Java EE version bundle.

An application server can be patched to upgrade the container of a particular service. The procedure may be official or undocumented. Upgrading to a minor version is usually painless and supported. Upgrading to a major version is usually unsupported and can often lead to incompatibilities.

Hope this helps.